# JQuery UI Datepicker - How to remove the "Done" button

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a Jquery datepicker. I want the button panel to be visible, but I do not want the "Done" button. 
According to the Jquery UI page [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#buttonbar)

> Display a button for selecting Today's date and a Done button for closing the calendar with the boolean showButtonPanel option. Each button is enabled by default when the bar is displayed, but can be turned off with additional options.

What are the options for turning off the **Done** button?
My code:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
  $( "#JourneyDate" ).datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showWeek: true,
        maxDate: "+0",
        dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried accessing the button using selector `ui-datepicker-close` and calling `remove()` but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it with CSS;

```
button.ui-datepicker-close {display: none;}​
```

Comment: That was quick! It works, thanks. I was trying visibility:hidden.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<style type="text/css"> .ui-datepicker-close { display: none; } </style>').appendTo("head");
```